# when __init__ is directly run, it can import a module, but when __init__ is imported, it cannot import the module

Tags: python, flask, ponyorm

I have 3 script structured as below

```
server.py
database/__init__.py
database/databaseConfig.py
```

`__init__.py` imported databaseConfig.py. When `__init__.py` is ran directly, it executes successfully. in server.py, there is `import database`. However, when server.py is ran, it throws the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'databaseConfig'
```

Why is this happening, and how to fix it ?

Here is the script for `__init__.py`

```
from pony.orm import Database
from databaseConfig import getDatabaseConfig

db = Database()
databaseConfig = getDatabaseConfig()
db.bind(databaseConfig["provider"], 
        user=databaseConfig["database_user"], 
        password=databaseConfig["database_user_password"], 
        host=databaseConfig["host"],
        database=databaseConfig["database_name"])
```

Here is the script for `databaseConfig.py`

```
def getDatabaseConfig():
    databaseConfig = { 
        "provider" : "postgres",
        "database_user" : "FlaCommerceServer",
        "database_user_password" : "password",
        "host" : "localhost",
        "database_name" : "FlaCommerce"
    }
    return databaseConfig
```

and `server.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from serverConfig import ServerConfig
import database

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(ServerConfig)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=app.config["SERVER_HOST"],port=app.config["SERVER_PORT"])
```

Comment: try `from .databaseConfig import getDatabaseConfig` this will tell python it is relative to the init or alternatively `from database.databaseConfig import getDatabaseConfig`

Comment: @JoranBeasley with that, running server.py doesnt throw error, but directly executing the `__init__.py` will throw ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: you should never directly execute an `__init__.py` script generally, if you want you can implement a `__main__.py` (which allows stuff like `python -m database`)or even some other generic named `cli.py` but you should not be directly invoking `__init__.py` (by convention) ... if you use the second suggestion(`from database.databaseConfig...`) it should work even if you disregard this earlier advise and invoke `__init__.py` directly

Comment: @JoranBeasley oh is that so, alright sorry i didnt know. But what if my file name isnt `__init__` but something else? i still need to understand why this is happening and how to fix it